# Why is my PC breaking my Mbed? - swd Error

Tags: embedded, mbed

I am using a nRF51-DK mbed board and programming it from both my mac and PC. However, when I use my PC to compile a program and then download the `.hex` to the board, I get a `Fail.txt` file show up in the mbed file system. It reads:

> SWD Error

After that, no matter what I do I get `fail.txt`

> TIMEOUT

I move to my mac, boot the mbed board in bootloader mode and then reinstall the latest firmware. After a reboot, the device works fine. When I try to instal any more programs from my PC, it breaks again.

Why is my PC breaking my mbed?

NB: I am using a Microsoft Surface Pro 3 running Windows 10 Pro x64

Comment: SWD is a hardware feature. Thisd does not sound like a software problem.

Comment: I didnt know mbed boards supported intel hex file formats.  I have only used  raw binary files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is suggested [here](https://developer.mbed.org/questions/973/SWD-error/):

> 1. Plug Board in, wait for solid status LED
> 2. Press and hold reset button and at same time drag blinky on to mass storage device.
> 3. Release reset and program should now load, no error.

I hope that makes sense to you - I have not used Mbed; I simply Googled "SWD Error" and several Mbed related hits popped up.  I was surprised because SWD (Single Wire Debug) is not peculiar to MBed, and expected to need *"SWD Error"+ mbed* as a search term; it seems this issue is common on mbed perhaps.

Anyway my advice in future is to always start by Googling the exact error message - it works in very many cases!

Comment: Thanks, I saw these. I was more interested in why I only have to do this on my PC, where mac is fine. which I couldn't find any answers to on Google.

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards : That is probably not a question to SO, but I imagine that a clue to the answer lies in how and why the solution fixes the problem - I am not familiar with mbed so cannot say.  I would guess that something you are loading onto the board is disabling the debug connection, and somehow the OSX environment is fixing or reinitialising it somehow - perhaps in a similar way to this manual work-around?

Comment: OK, I'll mark as answer as it does fix the problem. I'll do some more digging and try to come up with a more thorough answer. Thx.